# VBA - can't enter break mode while importing userform

Tags: vba, excel

If I try to import some data to my workbook with a command button, I always get the error message "can't enter break mode at this time"

```
Public Sub Add_WKA_Click()
     Static cnt As Long
     cnt = cnt + 1
     If cnt = 1 Then
         Call Add_WKA_Sheets
     ElseIf cnt = 2 Then
         Call Add_WKS_Sheets
     ElseIf cnt = 3 Then
         Call Add_PM_Sheets
     End If End Sub


 Sub Add_WKA_Sheets()
     Workbooks("Test.xlsm").VBProject.VBComponents.Import Filename:="C:\Code_Samples\UserForm\Add\Assignment_WKA1.frm"
     Workbooks("Test.xlsm").VBProject.VBComponents.Import Filename:="C:\Code_Samples\UserForm\Watch\Watch_WKA1.frm"
     [Assignment_WKA].Show 
End Sub
```

If i go through my code with F8, following Line shows the error message:

> Workbooks("Test.xlsm").VBProject.VBComponents.Import
>   Filename:="C:\Code_Samples\UserForm\Add\Assignment_WKA1.frm"

Hope someone can tell me why this happens and how i can solve it.

Comment: Does the form already exist? You say you want to import data, but your code is importing a VBA form into the VBA project. How did you get/create/generate the code that you have in your post?